# Why control disappears on post back?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have used TINYmCE in webforms which targets a control inside UpdatePanel.

It used to work on page load but kept disappearing at partial post backs i.e. selected index changed event etc so I used a method inside that event

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(string), txtBoxBody.ClientID, "TinyEditor()", true);
```

Now it's doesn't disappear. So i placed this inside each event which can cause postback but problem is that It appears only for once FOR EXAMPLE If one postback happens then it doesn't disappear but after that if i do 2nd postback that it disappears. It works for first postback only on whichever control.

.aspx code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function TinyEditor() {
            tinymce.init({
                selector: '#<%=txtBoxBody.ClientID%>',
                script_url: "../../tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js",
                height: 200,
                theme: 'modern',
                plugins: [
                  'advlist autolink lists pagebreak',
                  //'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars fullscreen',
                  'insertdatetime save contextmenu directionality',
                  ' paste textcolor textpattern print'
                ],
                toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | fontsizeselect | forecolor emoticons | fontselect emoticons | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify',
                //toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
                //image_advtab: true,
                fontsize_formats: '8pt 9pt 10pt 11pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 20pt 22pt 24pt 26pt 28pt 36pt 48pt 72pt',
                //templates: [
                //  { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
                //  { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
                //],
                content_css: [
                  '//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css',
                  '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
                ]
            });

        }




    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try slightly different approach. When you use UpdatePanel it generates some JS helper functions and events that you can hook up to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler_Page);

   function EndRequestHandler_Page(sender, args) {
       TinyEditor();
   }

   $(document).ready(function () {
       TinyEditor();
   });
</script>
```

That way you don't need to call ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock.

Comment: I have done this and every possible way of creating it but not luck